# I cannot run SDK manager

Tags: android, eclipse

when I try to run the **SDK** manager **Kasper-Sky** quarantine it and delete it from **SDK** tools and I have this message at eclipse

> [2013-06-17 10:18:50 - SDK Manager] [SDK Manager] 'D:\Work\MOBILE~1\Andriod\ANDROI~1\tools\lib\find_java.exe -s' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   [2013-06-17 10:18:50 - SDK Manager] [SDK Manager] operable program or batch file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found this i a forum on the web ... check it out :

[Forum answer](http://forum.kaspersky.com/index.php?s=3fc605f98541213dd18abca602f53eaf&showtopic=261915)

it basically tells you to try 2 things :

1) disable your antivirus while working.
2) add the sites of updating the sdk to the trusted sites list in Kasper-Sky.

Answer (score 2):

Disable Kaspersky while running SDK manager.
If eclipse can run it, consider to change your antivirus software or find a way to add the sdk folder to an ignore list of kaspersky.